# How can I get an url to a statement using a Chargify API?

Tags: api, url, invoice, chargify

How can I get an url to a statement using a Chargify API?

I want a user to be able to click a button in my application which would open an invoice in a new tab in browser in Chargify. I think I should use some Chargify API to obtain the url to open. Could someone help me find the API I need?

I tried to search for a needed API [here](https://reference.chargify.com/v1/statements/list-statements-for-a-site), but with no success so far.

I was only able to figure out how to retrieve an invoice as a plain text, as a basic html and as a usual html [here](https://reference.chargify.com/v1/statements/statements-intro#statement-presentation). Does it mean that Chargify expects me to only show invoice to a user inside my application and not inside chargify itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no publicly accessible url for a statement.  As you noted, you can retrieve the text or html (or pdf I think?) representation of it and display that to your user.

Or (if it is enabled) customers can go to the Billing Portal to view their statements.  https://help.chargify.com/settings/billing-portal.html

(The newer Relationship Invoicing platform does have public urls for the invoices. https://help.chargify.com/invoices/differences.html )